# SELECT distinct value in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

How to select DISTINCT value in mysql

```
id  r_id    cat_id
2   3   56
3   3   57
4   3   57
```

I want the output

```
id  r_id    cat_id 
2   3   56
3   3   57
```

I am using this code and getting r_id and cat_id but dont get id how can i

```
SELECT DISTINCT(r_id), cat_id FROM rmcat where rid = '123'
```

Comment: use `GROUP BY` and edit question title to *SELECT* not *SET*

Answer (score 0):

Use *GROUP BY* function.

```
select min(id) as id,max(r_id) as r_id,cat_id
from tablename
where rid = '123'
group by cat_id
```

Comment: using this also getting duplicate cat_id i.e 57 twice times I want unique cat_id and in response want to see all three columns

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try distinct for combination of these fields like this

`select distinct id, r_id, cat_id from rmcat where rid = '123'`